# Dropbox API from Chrome extension: Denying load of chrome-extension://[...]

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dropbox-api

I'm having trouble integrating the Dropbox API with a Chrome extension. Upon trying to authenticate the Dropbox, the redirect to the Dropbox confirmation/permission page works just fine, but the redirect back to the Chrome app fails. This is the error in the console:

```
Denying load of chrome-extension://mlabibnomhfmephibijgghejmmmbigpi/chrome_oauth_receiver.h…sGbCG&token_type=bearer&uid=14169733&state=oas_hquvrf6k_0.ycudjb24vysexw29. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
```

It seems that Chrome is preventing Dropbox from redirecting back to a page within the extension. Several hours of experimenting with permissions have yielded nothing.

Here's the `manifest.json`:

```
{

  "name": "MyApp",
  "description": "Description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {"16":"icon.png",
                    "48":"icon.png",
                    "128":"icon.png"},


  "manifest_version": 2,

  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "background",
    "bookmarks",
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "contentSettings",
    "contextMenus",
    "cookies",
    "debugger",
    "history",
    "idle",
    "management",
    "notifications",
    "pageCapture",
    "topSites",
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["backgroundcollector.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "<all_urls>",
    "chrome-extension://mlabibnomhfmephibijgghejmmmbigpi/chrome_oauth_receiver.html&response_type=token&state=oas_hquul1r4_0.1qwu7sh12pqzolxr",
    "chrome-extension://*/*"
  ],

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.dropbox.com; object-src 'self'",

  "key": "(included so that the extension gets a persistent extensionID)"

}
```

(The large number of permissions is the result of a lot of experimenting to get this to work. Obviously they'll be removed later.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a truckload of trash in your manifest file...
To allow other web pages to redirect to a page within your extension, you have to put this file at [`"web_accessible_resources"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html), without `chrome-extension://..`  prefix, like this:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "chrome_oauth_receiver.html"
],
```

You should request as few permissions as possible, see [Declare permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html) for a list of descriptions for each permission. I guess that you can get rid of almost every permission after reading that document.